# Substr() Runtime error: R6010 abort has been called

Tags: c++

I would like to convert a string into 4 ints.

```
bignum::bignum(const std::string& s){
    std::string tmp;
    const unsigned int s_size = sizeof(s)/sizeof(char);
    const unsigned int max_size = 4; 
    const unsigned int parts = s_size/max_size; 
    unsigned int x = 3;

    for(int i = s_size;i>0;i-=4){
        tmp = s.substr(s_size-max_size, max_size);
        std::cout << num[x] << std::endl;
        std::istringstream (tmp) >> num[x--];
    }
}
```

num is a vector, type of int.

I guess the problem is because of the substr is out of range, but somehow I can't make it to work.

Comment: sizeof(s) will give you the size of the string object not the number of characters in the string. for that you must call s.size() (or s.length())

Comment: I know, but I would like to work with every 4 bytes in the string. That's why I cut it into 4 bytes.

Maybe I'm wrong. Btw, with .lenght I got the same error.

Comment: [This](http://ideone.com/V5w2Sh) explains what I mean.

Comment: it would also help if we had an example of the kind of input you're expecting.

Comment: I think you want `i` instead of `s_size` in the `substr` call, right?

Comment: Another problem is if `s_size<4` (but `>0`), then `s_size-max_size` will become a quite large positive value, due to unsigned wraparound (but even without that wraparound, a negative index would not be valid).

Answer (score 2):

`std::string` is a class, not an array of `char`, so using `sizeof` will give an unexpected number. Just use the `size` member function instead:

```
const unsigned int s_size = s.size();
```

Comment: @user2351645 What do you mean by that?

Comment: I mean I get the same error message. But I guess I've just found the problem. So, I have byte values, and not indexes of a char sequence. That's the problem. :)